# How to assign string to a function in lua

Tags: arrays, list, lua

I am writing a calculator based on the script I have in Python and for the arithmatic operators I used:

```py
operations={'ADD':add,'PLUS':add,'SUM':add,'ADDITION':add,
            'SUB':sub,'SUBTRACT':sub, 'MINUS':sub,
            'DIFFERENCE':sub,'LCM':lcm,'HCF':hcf,'PRODUCT':mul,
            'MULTIPLY':mul,'MULTIPLICATION':mul,
            'DIVISION':div,'MOD':mod,'REMAINDER':mod,'MODULAS':mod}
```

This was the python one but the same idea does not work for Lua.
In the example the format goes:
`{'UserInput':Function}`
Any help would be appreciated.

I tried replacing `:` with `->` and `=` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of this python code:

```py
t = {"foo": "bar", "one": "two"}

t["foo"]
```

in lua is:

```lua
t = {["foo"] = "bar", ["one"] = "two"}

t["foo"]
```

or:

```lua
t = {["foo"] = "bar", ["one"] = "two"}

t.foo
```

Comment: `t["foo"]` also works in Lua and is the general form.

Comment: @lhf, so it does. I know less Lua than I do Python. Thanks.

Comment: so in the first example is foo or bar the function

Comment: The functions would go where "bar" and "two" are. Note: I'm only showing you the Lua syntax for a table, which is its approximate equivalent to a Python dictionary. I'm unsure whether the end result will actually achieve what you want. In Python, functions are objects just like anything else, so you can have them as values in a dictionary. I do not know if that also works in Lua.

Comment: Alright I will try this thank you!